# Linux has many dependencies when installing a small mp3 player

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, aptitude

I try to install a small audio player named "Audacious" with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install audacious
```

and it tells me that it depends audacious-plugins,

so I try to install the audacious-plugins,

one thing leads to another, there are numerous depends and it is just impossible to install all of them manually...

Is it even possible to install a software on Ubuntu Linux?

Is there a way to auto install all the depends?

---- Edit ----

I added the following sources list and now the dependencies can be auto installed.

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/Ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted
```

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: apt-get should install dependencies automatically.

Comment: Thanks Shevek and petersohn. I kind of solved this problem just now. I added some more software sources to my sources.list file. And the dependencies are installed automatically now. So I guess what the source list does is just "to tell the apt where to auto download the missing software", am i right?

Comment: Please post an answer, mentioning what sources were added by you. You can accept it later on and possibly help others

Comment: You might want to review your definition of "small audio player" :) There are much smaller players than audacious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add some sources and the problem is solved. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

`apt-get` installs all dependents, IIRC. Not sure why you're getting this problem. Try installng from Add/Remove Programs or Ubuntu Software centre

Comment: I think Xubunt default installation lacks enough souce list. After I added some sources, the dependencies are auto-installed now. So I guess what the source list does is just "to tell the apt where to auto download the missing software".